# Finder keeps freezing

Tags: macos, mac

I have a late 2013 Mac Pro (running Yosemite) and have had some problems with a frozen finder recently. When I select a tif/pdf/jpg file it freezes up on me and I have to force quit it. It freezes before it is able to splay the thumbnail of the file I have selected. It sometimes also freezes safari when I click on links or download something, although its a much more frequent problem for my finder.

Any help to get around this is appreciated, its a really annoying problem!!

Edit: spotlight also now freezes but my activity monitor is suggesting all is well

Comment: issue this command in Terminal:  `diskutil info disk0 | grep SMART`  Let me know what the output is.  I am assuming you have only one HDD

Comment: Yes, just one HDD. The result is 'SMART Status: Verified". Ive also noticed that my XQuartz won't open (if it is in any way related)

Comment: I just thought of something...is your drive a hybrid drive?  The reason I ask is because I have an iMac doing the **exact** same thing and the HDD has failed.  Try this utility. http://binaryfruit.com/drivedx  It's a trial, but that is all you need for now.

Comment: If the drive checks out OK, maybe on an outside shot, try removing any 3rd party quicklook generators from `~/Library/QuickLook`  `/Library/QuickLook` or `/System/Library/QuickLook`

Answer (score 1):

Check the Task Manager to see if anything (like Finder) is hogging Memory or CPU cycles, and check the disk activity as well.

Comment: spotlight has also started freezing now